# How to post to an Authorised User (with extended permissions) wall - Facebook JS SDK + Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this question has been asked a thousand time, but I have yet to come across a definitive answer.

How does an application (external website, so no fbml) post to a users wall, using JS and Graph API?

I have established extended permissions with users, and can post to walls using Facebooks sample code, however the variables within the script wont appear on FB.

For Example:

```
    function publish_test(){
    var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response);
  }
});
}
```

This posts to the users wall, however it does not contain the body. Any help on this would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FB.ui will pop up a confirmation dialog to the user, not sure if you want that or not.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui

This page has documentation about the FB.api call:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
Scroll down to the "Publishing" section and notice that there's no "body" parameter specified.  There is a "message" parameter though.  The other example you're looking at is probably incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I got this code working

`function graphStreamPublish(){
               var body = document.getElementById("txtTextToPublish").value;
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                         alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                         alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
               });
         }`